# Updating an NSFetchedResultsController with an NSPredicate that uses the current time

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data

I have an application that needs to filter objects based on timestamps. For example, lets say I want to filter an Event to only display Events that are in the past. I want to then display them in a UITableView. I would set up an NSFetchedResultsController like so:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Event" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"timeStamp" ascending:NO];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[sortDescriptor];

    // Filter based on only time stamps in the past
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"timeStamp < %@", [NSDate date]];
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate;

    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    // Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
    // nil for section name key path means "no sections".
    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
         // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
         // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. 
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

My question is this: what is the best way to update this view so that the filter is based on the current time? My existing solution is to set up a method like this:

```
- (void)updateFetchedResultsController {
    self.fetchedResultsController = nil;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Then I call that method on `viewWillAppear:` or `viewDidAppear:`. This works unless the user stays on the screen for a while.

I could also use an `NSTimer` and call `updateFetchedResultsController` once a minute or so but that causes issues if the user is scrolling through the table. Is there a better way to check if the data has changed? Since the data isn't changing I can't rely on any save events.

Comment: Check for change on data that isn't changing? So do you mean you want to remove items as they expire?

Comment: Yeah or add in new items that fall into the search scope.

Comment: What is the issue caused with scrolling?

Comment: Just that it can be jarring to the user to have the table update when they are not expecting it.

Comment: It might not be jarring if you use batch updates such that the changes are animated in, rather than calling `reloadData`.

Comment: But how can I calculate what the batch update would be since I can't use the built in NSFetchedResultsController methods?

Answer (score 0):

You only ever need to change the data on display when an items time is no longer valid. It has a date so you can calculate how long into the future that is and set a timer. You order the data so the next item to expire is always the first in the list.

To finesse, you can check for scrolling when the timer expires and delay the reload until the scroll animations have completed.

Comment: Unfortunately if I calculate the next "expiration" time ahead of time it won't update when new data is added and or removed.